# Can't compile project when replacing a reference to Json.NET with its source code

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 class library that I recently upgraded successfully  to .NET Core 1.0 RTM. I use it to implement some custom Json input and output formatters to include in the ASP.NET Core pipeline and therefore reference the Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 package to work with things like the JsonSerializerSettings object. The project compiles without errors.

However, I am having some runtime issues that I want to further investigate by stepping through the Newtonsoft source code. In .NET Core I have become accustomed to the flexibility of replacing a Nuget package reference with its source code by simply adding a reference to the checked out source in the global.json file (as nicely explained in [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/jun/09/using-and-debugging-external-source-code-packages-in-aspnet-5) blog post). This works great with things like the Microsoft AspNetCore source files from github, and I use it regularly.

For some reason, I can't manage to achieve this with the Newtonsoft source code. I have cloned the Newtonsoft source code from github and checked out the exact 9.0.1 tag that my project references. I have then added the source location to my global.json file in my solution. After this, Visual Studio 2015 finds the Newtonsoft project right away and successfully resolves it as a local reference. I can even see in my project references that the icon for the Newtonsoft reference has changed as it does when it uses a project from the same solution instead of the dll from the nuget server. Also, I don't see any warnings or errors like you sometimes find if references don't resolve properly.

However, when I try to compile the project, I now get the following compile error:

> Error  CS0012  The type 'JsonSerializer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

The error makes no sense to me as the project references resolved fine without errors, and if I remove the source reference and let it take the compiled version from nuget, the project compiles fine. This is the project.json of my project:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "description": "...",
    "authors": [ "..." ],
    "buildOptions": {
        "xmlDoc": true
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "net451": { },
        "netstandard1.6": {}
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Even though the package is versioned as 9.0.1, from project.json it says `1.0.0-*` (https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/9.0.1/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/project.json#L2)...not sure if that confuses build...try removing the version info in your project.json file and try again..

Comment: Have you tried using `"Newtonsoft.Json": { "target": "project" }`?

Comment: @KiranChalla Yes, I had noticed that too and had changed the version in the json.net project to 9.0.1 already, this was required for the reference to be resolved. But even with the resolved reference the build error remains.

Comment: @svick Tried your suggestion too, but it makes no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This reason for this is that "Newtonsoft.Json" is strong named.

You need a `<dependentAssembly>` for that. This is in the old .config ways done like this: (in `<runtime>`)

```xml
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.1.0." newVersion="9.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you could be right, but I can't figure out how to configure this in ASP.NET Core. And it looks like I'm not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466304/asp-core-wrong-assembly-redirect-on-publish